# SearchBox which i have used in fragment class is not responding with the Cardview

Tags: android

The Seaarch Box is not responding with the Cardview,which has the names,ex-Employee Name,i need to search by names which are in cardview.
I need to work it as similarly as contact search.The Name we type on Search Box that Cardview Come Up.
Below is the Code.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < enggFragModels.size() - 1; i++) {
      searchName = enggFragModels.get(i).getEmployeeName();
      Log.i("EnggVIew", "enggViewMInterface: " + searchName);
      enggFragModels.get(i).getEmployeeName()
    };

    strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add(searchName);
    arr[i] = searchName;}

    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        Log.i("for loop", " arr: " + arr[j]);
    }

    adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.frame_engineer,R.id.name_engineer, arr);                             

    Log.i("adapter2", "enggViewMInterface: "+arr);

    mListview.setAdapter(adapter2);
    Log.i("mlistView", "enggViewMInterface: "+arr);

    mSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, 
            int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.i("inside overrideloop", "beforeTextChanged: "+arr);
                adapter2.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,       int i1, int i2) {
                Log.i("inside 2nd overrideloop", "beforeTextChanged"+arr);
                adapter2.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
                adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Edit the question with your code, or will have to down vote for posting incomplete question

Comment: Put your code with proper format.

Comment: Ya i will do in proper format,and i thank you for guiding as am new to android.